# ImageView zoom animation cuts off image slightly

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I am trying to implement zoom image functionality for images in the view. The view is kind of gallery view with images. I have applied the scale animation using xml and the animation works properly. The issue is when the image zooms the sides of image is cut off. I am using circularimageview as the image needs to be shown in a circle. I have tried increasing spacing between images but still the issue persists, the images gets cut off slightly when zoomed.

Can someone point out what may be the issue ?

The xml that I use for scale animation is

```
<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.15"
    android:toYScale="1.15" >
</scale>
```

Comment: add few snaps to explain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was an issue with margins that was given around the image. I was able to resolve it by giving different margin values.

Comment: Add margins helped. Thanks :)